# Render emoji in browser from JS

Tags: javascript, emoji

I have a JSON object with strings defined like this: `var obj = {text:"Iconic. \n\\ud83d\\udd25"}`, where `\ud83d\udd25` should be the fire emoji.

EDIT: The string is passed in this escaped format from an external source.

I then pass this value into a div as

```
var caption = document.getElementById('caption');
caption.innerHTML = obj.text;
```

I also have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` set in my head.

How do I get this to render as the emoji rather than the unicode string?

Comment: If you want `\u` to start a unicode escape, **don't** escape the ```\```! It's just `var obj = {text:"Iconic. \n\ud83d\udd25"}` (Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo)

Comment: @Quentin - this isn't a typo, unfortunately. This is the format the string is passed to me from an external source. Is there a way I can work around this?

Comment: Is this one specific thing that needs fixing, or an example of what they get wrong with all the escaped characters?

Comment: It's all, I think. For example, new lines are coming through in the string as `\\n` so rendering as `\n` - but I'm happy just to remove these so they're not causing issues.

Comment: Eugh. Named and numbered escapes all broken. Ick. Are you sure you can't fix this at the point the data is passed through to the page? e.g. is the escaping happening because you are using a template language that generates the JS and escapes special characters?

Comment: I think the issue is that the string is being picked up from a Google sheet where it's formatted "correctly" but then parsed into a "JS readable" string. I have some control over the original string in the Google sheet, so I guess I could replace with something identifiable there to prevent it from being escaped but I'd prefer another solution if there is one.

Comment: It's the code that converts it to a JS Readable string you should probably be looking at.

Comment: Yep. But that's the bit I have no control over. It's a Google program...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing this at source so that the data is not double escaped would be the best approach to solving this problem.

If you cannot do that, then you can wrap the data in double quotes to turn it into a string containing a JSON representation of a string, then parse that JSON.

```js
const obj = {
  text: "Iconic. \\n\\ud83d\\udd25"
};
const text = JSON.parse('"' + obj.text + '"');
var caption = document.getElementById('caption');
caption.innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<table>
  <caption id="caption"></caption>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

NB: In a comment you said *For example, new lines are coming through in the string as `\\n` so rendering as `\n`* so I updated the code in  your example to match that. This won't work if that isn't the case.